# Allow testers access to a specific build in iTunes Connect, without sending an invite

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

We have about 100 testers in our iTunes Connect in total, without about 20-30 of them on each of our apps.  When we push a new build (sometimes just with bug-fixes for *specific* people), we'd like to be able to give *access* to all our testers, but either send *no* emails at all, or just emails to the specific people that are affected by that update.

Case in point, unfortunately one of our old keys expired yesterday, and someone was trying to get the app today.  So we sorted our key issue, up the version, re-sign the ipa and re-upload to iTunes Connect.  We *don't* want to prevent access to any of our previous testers, and we *don't* want to email all our users, because it's *not* a new build, just a re-signed old build.

Currently, and extremely frustratingly, we can't see any way to currently do that, despite that being exactly how it worked when TestFlight was TestFlight.

Comment: afaik not possible with how Apple implemented Testflight

Comment: That really, really, really would be a crazy policy and completely shortsighted, and damaging for companies.  We're in discussions with publishers at the moment, and we don't want to revoke anyone's access, in case they come back, but we don't want to email people saying there's a "new" build, when it really isn't.  The changes we made are literally for 5 people, no more.